# Ruby on Rails - new page and custom route is not displaying the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I just want an info page with text and no instance variables.

I created the `info.html.rb` file with just `"test"` in it.

I created the controller action in `projects_controller.rb`

```
def projects_info
end
```

In the `routes.rb` I did

```
resources :projects do
  collection do
  get :projects_info
  end
end
```

After `rake routes` I have

```
projects_info_projects GET  /projects/projects_info(.:format)  projects#projects_info
```

In the script I have

```
link_to t(:info), projects_info_projects_path
```

But what I get in the browser is a **list** of the /public folder??

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDV7w.png)

I have no idea what I am missing.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the link address in the browser?

Comment: Why don't you call the file projects_info.html.rb? Is it in views/projects?

Comment: @Sharj it is `myapp.com/projects/projects_info` [at]Pablo Now I changed the name of the file/page (which is empty so far) to projects_info.html.rb but there is no change. The link above seems correct(?) but it leads me to `/myappdir/public` (I use suse enterprise btw)

Comment: @Pablo yes, the file is in `views/projects`

Comment: Please do not add tags to your question title, including `[solved]` tags, as it may be perceived as unneeded noise by the community. When an answer is accepted, this is an acceptable way to show that the question has been answered.